# Why linux (ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) mounts windows (ntfs) partition without any record in fstab?

Tags: mount, ubuntu-20.04, fstab

I just detected that my windows (ntfs) partition is always mounted but doesn't have any record in fstab.
How and why ubuntu doing that? Is it not too obscure, why not place a record to fstab, it becomes a mess...

The proof (just in case)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=24ec45af-0daf-4c51-ae97-c6eb09c9b3bc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=5C0E-7502  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`blkid` output of windows record

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="82A210E9A210E387" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f89ba644-4f63-497a-9af1-4e01daa9958f"
```

Comment: Where is the NTFS partition being mounted?

Comment: @Nattgew `/media/david/Windows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is probably mounting the drive with [FUSE](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/fuse.4.html) which is different from the method of mounting through fstab. FUSE allows the filesystem code to be more portable than if it were integrated into the kernel.

If you're looking to disable this behavior, you can see the options [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/89244/15341) and [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369154/63286)